# Is there a way to boost the output volume in android tablets (or phones) above the allowed maximum?

Tags: android, audio, max, volume

I have a tablet whose volume I have set to maximum, and I listen to the output from my program   through a headset which is also set to maximum. My program takes the input through the microphone, performs some DSP on it, calculates a gain, applies this gain and sends the output to the headphones. This gain value is greater than 1 and I further multiply it with t a constant, whose value I have determined through trial and error, so that the output in the headphone is just undistorted. But I still feel the output is not loud enough.

Is there any way I can further increase the volume of the output, (preferably without distortion) either programmatically or using something else such as a bluetooth headset? I need the output to come through a headset, so I cannot use lodspeakers that plug into the wall outlets.

Comment: Sounds like it is already pretty loud. Are you having trouble with certain quiet parts? You could apply compression (though this is technically distortion). You can also, simply use more sensitive headphones.

Comment: I want to apply some noise reduction techniques and use the smartphone as a sound amplifier for individuals who are hard of hearing and I think making the output louder would make it better

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for. Any further increase in volume on the tablet is by definition going to introduce distortion, but if the goal is to make it inaudible, a compressor or limiter is probably going to help. Still the maximum volume is going to be limited by the hardware.

Comment: What @BjornRoche said. It's quite likely that the tablet already is running a peak limiter or dynamic range compressor on the headset output path at the platform level, as well as dynamic range compression on the microphone input path. If you've attached any `AudioEffects` to your output you might want to remove them, since they often incur some attenuation in order to leave some headroom for the effect.

Comment: I haven't used any audio effects; however, I haven't understood all the parameters of the AudioRecord and AudioTrack constructor; the first parameter is AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION. Does this make anuy difference in the maximum volume of the output? The developers website does not have any details on what they exactly are, but I see that there are other options such as ringer, alarm and notification in the AudioManager and MediaRecorder.AudioSource class (which the AudioRecord constructor seems to accept as well). Do they make any difference to the maximum output?